# Bootstrap Modal Hide is not working at Laravel 7

Tags: javascript, jquery, laravel, twitter-bootstrap, modal-dialog

I try to close the automatic capital when I click "ok" after a successful upload of data, but when I click "ok" the capital does not close / hide

this is my blade

```
complete:function(res){
                console.log(res);
                if(res.responseJSON !== undefined){
                    if(res.responseJSON.status === true){
                        table.ajax.reload();
                        Swal.fire({
                            title:'Success',
                            text:res.responseJSON.messages,
                            icon:'success'
                        }).then((done)=>{
                            if (done) {
                                resetForm() 
                                $("my-modal").modal("hide")
                                table.ajax.reload();
                            }
                        })
                    } else {
```

Comment: what is "my-modal" in $("my-modal").modal("hide") ??

Comment: If "my-modal" is class use ".my-modal" or if it's id use "#my-modal", it should work

Comment: "my-modal" is id, i change "$("#my-modal").modal("hide");" to function, and call it, it work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to replace
`$("my-modal").modal("hide");`
by
`$("#my-modal").modal("toggle");`